# Removing kernel leftovers

Tags: kernel

I downloaded 3.11-rc3 kernels from kernel.org and built. Even though I had 8 GB free space, somehow I ran out of space and I interrupted the installation at `make modules` step.

Now I would like to remove leftovers to gain more space, but couldn't find where it installed all the files.

How can I remove?

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should be able to simply remove the kernel source tree. All operations are done in the kernel source tree until the kernel is actually installed.